# Yet another LazyInitializationException even with OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm getting the dreaded LazyInitializationException in my web application using Spring 3/ Hibernate 3.6 and jsp. I have OpenSessionInViewFilter in my web.xml but still it seems like my HSession is getting closed or invalidated somehow. I have also checked that there is no exception caused by my application.

Here is my web.xml

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>hedgebenefits</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Context.xml is:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hedgebenefits.*"/>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/managerie"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hedgebenefits.domain"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Jsp is:

```
<tr>
    The list is :
    <td>
    <c:forEach var="admin" items="${admins}">
        Admin is ${admin.username},
        <c:forEach var="sector" items="${admin.sectors}">
            sector is ${sector.name}
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Service is annotated with @Transactional:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService {


    private AdminDao adminDao;

    @Autowired
    public AdminServiceImpl(AdminDao adminDao) {
        this.adminDao = adminDao;
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public List<Admin> listAllAdmins() {
        return adminDao.listAllAdmins();
    }
}
```

Dao is:

```
@Repository
public class AdminDaoImpl implements AdminDao{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public AdminDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public List<Admin> listAllAdmins() {
        List<Admin> adminList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Admin.class)
                .setMaxResults(5)
                .list();
        return adminList;
    }
}
```

Edit: Added the controller and stacktrace

Controller is:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
@SessionAttributes(value = "admin")
public class AdminRegistrationController {

    ...    
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list")
    public ModelAndView listRegisteredAdmins() {
        List<Admin> admins = adminService.listAllAdmins();
        return new ModelAndView(LIST_ADMINS.getViewName()).addObject("admins", admins);  
    }
```

Stacktrace is:

```
   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp at line 15

12:         <td>
13:         <c:forEach var="admin" items="${admins}">
14:             Admin is ${admin.username},
15:             <c:forEach var="sector" items="${admin.sectors}">
16:                 sector is ${sector.name}
17:             </c:forEach>
18:         </c:forEach>


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    root cause

    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.hedgebenefits.domain.Admin.sectors, no session or session was closed
        org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
        org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
        org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
        org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
        org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
        org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:348)
        org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:224)
        org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.list_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(list_jsp.java:149)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.list_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(list_jsp.java:112)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.list_jsp._jspService(list_jsp.java:70)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

It seems that I'm missing something obvious here, but can't figure out what?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or point out which line of the jsp is triggering the exception? Also show your controller code, are you putting/getting stuff from the httpsession i.e., are you working with detached objects?

Comment: @gkamal Added the controller and stacktrace, I'm not doing anything like this.

Comment: Everything looks to be in order.  You should turn on debug logging for spring (atleast HibernateTransactionManger & OpenSessionInViewFilter) and check when & why session is closed.  You can also try the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor which is more suitable for springMVC apps. You can also add some code in the service to check if the fetching of sectors collection works correctly (there are some edge cases where failure to load gets reported as lazy initialization). Are you doing something in the getSectors method like copying to new collection?

Comment: Nothing as such, but I'll go ahead as per ur suggestion and investigate and come back to you soon! Thanks.